# Weka IBk parameter details (distanceWeighting, meanSquared)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I am using kNN algorithm to classify. In weka they have provided various parameter setting for kNN. I am intersted to know about the distanceWeighting, meanSquared.

In distanceWeighting we have three values (No distance weighting, weight by 1/distance and weight by 1-distance). What are these values and what is their impact?

Can someone please expalin me? :)

Comment: This question is about clustering and kNN, you may consider adding these tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one uses "no distance weighting", then the predicted value for your data points is the average of all k neighbors. For example

```
# if values_of_3_neigbors = 4, 5, 6 
# then predicted_value = (4+5+6)/3 = 5
```

For 1/distance weighting, the weight of each neigbor is inversely proportional to the distance to it. The idea is: the closer the neighbor, the more it influences the predicted value.  For example

```
# distance_to_3_neigbors = 1,3,5
# weights_of_neighbors = 1/1, 1/3, 1/5  # sum = 1 + 0.33 + 0.2 = 1.53
# normalized_weights_of_neighbors = 1/1.53, 0.33/1.53,  0.2/1.53 = 0.654, 0.216, 0.131
# then predicted_values = 4*0.654 + 5*0.216 + 6*0.131 = 4.48
```

For 1-distance it is similar. This is only applicable when all your distances are in the [0,1] range.

Hope this helps

Comment: can we check these 3 values when k=1? Or k>1 to use 1/distance weighting and 1-distance weighting? :)

Comment: For k=1 you consider only 1 neighbor, so distance weighting makes no sense. If you use _some_ , the only effect may be slowing your code a little bit

Comment: can you please tell me the ideal K value to start with? :)

Comment: This depends  on your data and inside knowledge. Anyway, k>1. Odd values like 5,7 are typically reasonable

Comment: In my problem I have like 200 features of 1000 users. Can you give me a suggestion for the k value :)